# How to install system.random. Maybe cabal issue in version 8 of stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 with stack ghci version 8. I want to import System.Random in Haskell but it seems I am having trouble that may involve Cabal. I have seen similar posts on this website but they usually say it is because of an older version but I am using version 8.

I get the error:

```
Failed to load interface for ‘System.Random’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

which tells me I have problems with System.Random. Looking online, I found that I need to first install Cabal.

When I type

```
Cabal --version
```

I get

```
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library
```

which tells me I already have it. So when I try to update with

```
sudo apt-get install cabal-install cabal update
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cabal
E: Unable to locate package update
```

which is weird. If I ignore it and try to install random anyways through

```
cabal install random
```

I get

```
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
random-1.1
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

So it seems I also have the random package of cabal. But I can't load a program with the

```
import System.Random
```

command.

EDIT: It seems I have stack ghci version 8.0.1 and ghci version 7.10.3.
The System.random loads in ghci but not stack ghci.

I also get the following when I try to load a file in stack. Entering

```
stack ghci R.hs
```

I get

```
Warning: Couldn't find a component for file target /home/aa/workspace/share/haskell/chenw/hw4/R.hs. Attempting to load anyway.
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/aa/.ghc/ghci.conf
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/ghci19674/ghci-script
```

Does this mean there is something wrong with my install of stack?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install cabal-install cabal update` failing isn’t weird. The command is `cabal update`; it has nothing to do with apt-get.

Comment: @Ryan, I just tried "cabal update && cabal install cabal-install" and it still didn't work.

Comment: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#adding-dependencies. `stack install` might work, too.

Comment: You didn't give the command used to get the first error message. But does `stack ghci --package random` fix it?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman. Yes it did, thanks! As a followup, is stack functioning correctly? Is it supposed to be able to load a program File.hs when I type "stack ghci File.hs" or is my stack behaving the proper way by not loading and only going into prelude?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I almost never use the ghci command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `stack`, and assume you have a working `stack`, you don't have to install anything via `apt-get`.

First, update your `stack`

```
stack update
```

Make sure you having the right `resolver` [version number](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.0/package/random-1.1) for your packages

- If you want to use stack globally ,i.e., `stack ghci <source.hs>`. Check `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml`.
- If you manage your project using `stack`, i.e,. `stack new <project>`, `stack build`. Check project's stack.yaml

To use `stack` globally (anywhere)

- install random by `stack install random`
- using GHCi by `stack ghci` and `:load <source.hs>`
- compile source by `stack ghc <source.hs>`
- run your program by `stack exec <executable_name>`

You can force stack to use specific resolver by using `--resolver=`.

Example: using latest lts

```
$ stack --resolver=lts setup
$ stack --resolver=lts install random
$ stack --resolver=lts ghci
```

To use `stack` in a project directory (`stack.yaml` exists), you don't need to install package manually; `stack` will install it for you, if needed, when `stack build`. But you have to edit `<project.cabal>`

```
build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , random
```

Comment: How did you know that the name of the `System.Random` package was just `random`? Where did you find that information?